# Sign Github commits using dynamic signingkey

Tags: git, github, gnupg, direnv

I have a Github account linked with 2 email addresses, (Personal + work). I'm only able to sign commits coming from one account, using `git config --global user.signingkey MySigningKey` because the key is associated with one email.

I'm using [direnv](https://direnv.net/) to commit using different emails depending on the directory that I'm in, it works setting an .envrc with an enviroment variable like `export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=someemail@gmail.com`.
I was wondering if there was a similar solution to define dynamic signing keys

Comment: You can set `user.signingkey` on repository basis (without the `--global` flag) to override the default for some repos. This is obviously only a solution for a limited number of repositories, though.

Answer (score 1):

Note: if your email is stored in the local configuration of a Git repository (with git config user.email), your commit will use the right email when you need to sign commits.
Meaning you would not need `direnv`.

In order to avoid the *global* setting to interfere with repositories using the *other* email, you could:

- either declare `user.signingkey` only in the repositories using the correct `user.email`.
- or define on your machine a separate user account for working on those repositories (meaning you can keep the `user.signingkey` option *global* for that separate account)